# Copygroup membership from one group to another powershell

Tags: powershell, security

I was hoping someone can point me in the right direction please.

Im trying to do something that should be pretty straight forward i think, but i can;t get it to work or can i find any similar examples.  basically, i want to be able to do the following:

Look at an existing Security Group 'Member of' groups and then add those member of groups to another/new group.  So for example, group 1 is member of 'A, B, C' groups.  Group 2 is memebr of none.  I want to copy the membership of Group 1 to Group 2, but NOT users (although if that was a must they could then be removed easily enough.

What i dont need to worry about is any users, or copying groups that users are members of etc.

Thanks

Thanks for that... so if i look at something like:

```
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity 'TARGETGROUP' -Members (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'SOURCEGROUP' -Recursive -Server Server1) -Server Server1
```

This adds users from Sourcegroup to Targetgroup, but im not worried about users, its the sourcegroups 'Member of' details i want addding to the targetgroup if that makes sense?

I can extract the info from the targetgroup using something like

```
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Identity 'SourceGroup' -Properties memberof -Server Server1 | select MemberOf | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap
```

But then cant seem to do much with importing that info into the new group.  Hope that makes sense? :)

Thanks for the info: That looks to be trying to add the groups from Source into the Members of section as oppose to the member of section for the groups, if that makes sense? it states 'Add-ADGroupMember : A universal group cannot have a local group as a member' which would suggest its tring to add the groups a s amember of the new group, not into the 'member of' of the new group..

Just wanted to share the following (in crude form) as this doen what i was after:
Get-ADGroup -Identity %SOURCE% -Properties memberof -Server SERVER1 |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty memberof |
Add-ADGroupMember -Members %TARGET% -Server SERVER1

Thanks for your help chaps.

Comment: welcome to SO, this site is here to help you when you have specific problems with your code, not for conceptual questions. For your case you want to have a look at `Get-ADGroupMember` and `Add-ADGroupMember`. When you have some code and it doesn´t work people will gladly help you out. (How to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: here try this: `Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "TARGET" -Members (get-adgroup "SOURCE" -prop memberof).memberof`

Comment: Don't use any `Format-*` cmdlet if you intend to further work with Objects.

Comment: Thanks Paul, tried the updated code and tinkered but dont think it was trying to do what i wanted.

Comment: Lotpings - thanks for that, i will go back to a previous script block that i was trying and retest

Comment: An easy way to get only the groups is something like Get-ADGroupMember -identity <group name> | Where-Object {$_.objectClass -eq 'group'}. This will fetch only the members which are of the objectClass group (so no users will be returned).

Comment: thanks for that - its getting that info back from a variable and added the details into a new group that i'm stuck with, eg use the baove to return the groups, then add a new group be a member of those groups...maybe im thinking of this the wrong way round and need to return the groups, then create the new group and add the new group into the reutned groups, if that makes sense?